# Problem proving a multivariable limit using sandwich theorem

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to prove that the following limit exists:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2-x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} =1 $$

I am able to deduce that the limit exists and equals 1 by trying a few values. I tried to prove using the sandwich theorem, however, it seems to be wrong:

$$\displaystyle 0<\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\leq1$$
$$\displaystyle 0<\frac{x^2+y^2-x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq x^2+y^2-x^2y^2$$
$$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x^2+y^2-x^2y^2 = 0 $$
$$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2-x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} = 0 $$

Can anyone help me to find the right proof and tell me how did I use sandwich theorem wrong?

thanks!

Comment: That is because $\frac 1{x^2+y^2}$ could be greater than $1$.

Comment: Not sure if it is just my brain is stuck or somehow, would u mind telling me how is that possible?

Comment: Take $x = y = 0.5$.

Comment: Oh right. I was just thinking about integers. So how should I prove this?

Comment: all you need is $2|xy| \leq x^2 + y^2 $  so $4x^2 y^2 \leq .....$

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: develop $(|x|-|y|)^2\ge 0$

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I am just not really good at coming up with a particular inequality to prove a limit.

Comment: @YanZhuang  if you are replying to a specific comment, you should put an @ sign and the beginning of that username. I think you meant me....  You should be seeing a little red flag in the upper right of the screen  (at least if you are using a web browser). I had left this question, I got no flag, I just happened to return, which I sometimes do sometimes don't

Comment: @WillJagy Okay thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

If $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, one has that

\begin{align*}
0 < y^{2} \leq x^{2} + y^{2} \Longleftrightarrow 0 < \frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow 0 < \frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{x^{2} + y^{2}} \leq x^{2}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes everything's good now. Thanks a lot for the hint

Comment: You are welcome!